# Gauge freedom when solving Einstein field equation

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, diffeomorphism-invariance

In Weinberg's *Gravitation and Cosmology*, Ch7, the Einstein field equations give us 6 independent equations (totally 10 equations but $∇^\mu G_ {\mu \nu} =0$ gives 4 constraints) while $g_{\mu \nu}$ has 10 indepent components. The remaining 4 freedom are said to correspond to the gauge freedom, which is just the choice of the coordinates.

But, if I want to do a coordinate transformation, shouldn't I apply it to $T_{\mu \nu}$ as well? Then the components of $T_{\mu \nu}$ are changed, so do the equations.

What I mean is, if I first choose a coordinate system (to write down the equations I have to do this) and solve $g_{\mu \nu}$, my general solution will still contain 4 degree of freedom, and any two particular solutions is different from a coordinate transformation. But after a coordinate transformation the equations are changed(numerically, at least), so why are the transformed $g_{\mu \nu}$ still the solution of the original equations?